# Can random variables can be dependent if their squares are independent?

Tags: probability-theory, independence

Given two random variables X and Y. It is known that $X^2$ and $Y^2$ are independent. Is it possible for X and Y to be dependent?

Comment: Please edit to include your thoughts.

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Here is an example. A pair of coins, say the left and right coin, is flipped repeatedly. The RV $L$ takes the value $1$ if the left coin comes up heads, and $-1$ if it comes up tails. Similarly, the RV $R$ is $1$ if the right coin says heads and $-1$ if tails. We assume all coin tosses are independent, with heads and tails equally likely. Now define $X:=L+1$ and $Y:=L(R+1)$. Clearly $X^2$ and $Y^2$ are independent. However, $Y$ can only be $-2$ or $2$ (each with probability $\frac14$) when, respectively, $X=0$ or $X=2$ (each with probability $\frac12$).

Comment: Oh, I think I've got you. But is it enough to say that $E(X^2Y^2) = E(X^2)E(Y^2)$ for $X^2$ and $Y^2$ to be independent?

Comment: No, it's not enough. I have deleted that remark, as I don't think it's helpful. One way to establish independence, for discrete RVs as in this example, is to show that P$[(X,Y)=(a,b)]=\,$P$(X=a)$P$(Y=b)$ for all $a$ and $b$. Here, there are six possible values for $(a,b)$; so it's easier just to consider dependence or independence directly according to the intuitive definition.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple counterexample. Let $X$ and $Y$ be discrete random variables with joint probability mass function $p(x,y)=P(X=x,Y=y)$ defined as $p(-1,0)=p(0,-1)=p(0,0)=p(1,1)=\frac14$, otherwise $p(x,y)=0$. Plainly $X$ and $Y$ are dependent, while $X^2$ and $Y^2$ are independent.